# Sorting out numbers in for loops

Tags: javascript

So I am determining which is a prime number and which isn't, but I am just not understanding how it ends up with the correct output.

So the first starts at 2 and loops by 1 to 100. Easy.
But the second starts at 0, and loops by y + itself, this would make sense, but in determining the primes, it should mess up, atleast I thought
it's like: 1+3 = 4 or 2 + 4 = 6 or 3 + 5 = 8

and that works, but what happens to let's say the 15? that isn't a prime number.
How is numbers like that sorted in the loop?

```
var prim = [];
 var notprim = [];
  for(var x = 2; x <= 100; x++){
    if(!notprim[x]){
        prim.push(x);


        for(var y = 0; y <= 100; y = y+x){
            notprim[y] = true;
            document.write(y);
        }
    }
   }
```

Comment: What is your algorithm? Can you spell it out?

Comment: Algorithm name is prime sieves. link to wiki http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_primes#Prime_sieves

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an *Array* `notprim` that you can imagine as `[undefined × 100]`, and `!!undefined === false`, i.e. *undefined* is *falsy*

If for some number `n` you have `notprim[n]` *falsy*, you assume it means `n` must be a prime number and add it to another Array, `prim`

Then you set all multiples of `n` to be *truthy* in `notprim`, i.e. if `n` is `3`, you set `notprim[n * x] = true;`, i.e. *0, 3, 6, 9, 12, **15**, etc*

You then look for the next *falsy* index in `notprim` to start again

---

The reason the first loop starts at `2` is because `2` is the first *prime number*, starting from `1` or `0` would cause the assumption that "`notprim[n]` *falsy* means `n` is a prime number" to fail

Great, but what about the other loop? Well, one way of going through `n * x` is to add `n` to itself `x` times. When you're thinking of it this way, you can then limit how high you go without knowing a maximum multiplier in advance by looking at the running `t`otal, for example in a `for` loop

```
for (t = 0; t <= 100; t = t + n)
    // t ∈ nℤ, 0 <= t <= 100
```

---

> but what happens to lets say the 15?

When you've found the prime number `3`, you then flag all multiples of `3` to be excluded from your search for primes. `15` is a multiple of `3` so gets flagged as *not a prime*. Hence your `if (!notprim[x])` does not pass

---

You can reduce the number of iterations this code needs by excluding `0` and `x` from the second `for` loop; i.e. begin from the index `y = 2 * x`